# How to get the schema name when I have table name?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table name but I am not sure in which schema that table exists. How to find the schema name?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
Select owner
from dba_tables
where table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME'
```

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables014.htm) you can find something more.

Answer (score 11):

Something like this should get the name of the table and the the schema it belongs to .

```
select owner, table_name 
 from all_tables 
 where table_name like 'GL%';
```